# Height on page coming from an unknown source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I usually build my wordpress sites by using a theme and creating a child theme. Generally I have done this with Wordpress 2013, but this time decided to take a crack at it with 2014. I have run into a few issues but finally landed on one I have not been able to resolve.

http://demo.diocesan.com/robert/

On this page, it tells me the page has a height of 2000+ px. When I try to find where this height is computed, I find nothing. I have set the height on many different elements to 1000px (even the HTML tag itself) and I still have this mysterious height value.

I suspect this has something to do with the 2014 masonry script (Admittedly I am not great with javascript) and any direction on this would be helpful. So my question - Does anyone upon glancing at this know where the height is coming from and what steps I can take to remove it?

Comment: Question doesn't make sense and there's no code. What is "it" that tells you it's 2000px, there's no need to set the height of most containers usually.

Comment: It's not applied by JS - disabling JS then viewing the page still shows the excess height above the footer

Comment: It's difficult to throw down some code showing what I'm trying to do when I did nothing to make the height appear - so there's that. And 'it' being the inspector tool - you know, just your common sense web development here. Literal weirdos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the CSS on `#secondary` - it has `min-height: 100vh` applied, which will make that one element **at least** one full viewport tall.

It's then hidden because the following element (`#primary`) which contains the content is given a `float: left` which makes it move up, so that it appears that the gap is beneath `#primary`, even though it's not.

Removing the `min-height` on `#secondary`, or setting it to a sensible value, will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it was part of the theme and I hadn't overridden it. Wonder why the inspector tool wasn't doing the trick. Also, holy wow the people on this site are INSANELY PICKY about how things are worded. Common sense would have helped anyone figure out this question, and in particular anyone actually able to answer the question (like yourself) would have understood. Good lord.

Comment: @chucktowski Yeah, people can get a bit precious about "Hey I have to click a link and then I can see the live code, with the live **massive blank space**, I want to instead get a cut-down basic hash of something a bit approximate so it's easy for me". This is a legit "Here's the full site, take a look" situation IMO